# HighCharts in AngularJS with dynamic data

Tags: angularjs, json, highcharts, highcharts-ng

I'm trying to implement [highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/) in AngularJS project. The chart executes properly with the static data. With dynamic data (data recieved via AJAX call) it's not working at all. I'm looking for an example of HighCharts with dynamic data in AngularJS.

Comment: Post your code here so we can understand issue is

Comment: Are you using any directive to work with highcharts?

Comment: I was following this example: https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/194-using-highcharts-with-angular-js/. I just replaced categories and series[{data}] with the dynamic data.

Comment: Do you encounter any errors? Do you receive correct data on ajax success? Provide us with full example.

Answer (score 0):

First: verify that your ajax call returns data correctly encoded.
Second: make sure you call .chart() in your callback.